# exporting types in an export = environment

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am creating a `typings.d.ts` file for a module that has no typings. However it would be good to get access to some of the types inside the declaration.

This seems to be not possible when I use the `export =`

```
declare module 'test' {

  export = class Test {
  }

  export interface ITestObj { // this gives an error because of the above export
    key : string;
    secret : string;
  }

}
```

Is there another way in which I can structure my typings file so I can also export the types as well.

---

NOTE:
The above structure of `export = class Test` is required as that is how the module is working.

Comment: The error in the TypeScript playground is, "An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements."

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> Is there another way in which I can structure my typings file so I can also export the types as well? The above structure of `export = class Test` is required as that is how the module is working.

Unfortunately, what you want is not supported. [From the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> The `export =` syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module.

In other words, if the module uses `export =`, then the module can export only one object.